# Using cv::Mat image(opencv) how can i detect object?

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

Using

```
Mat image;
```

I used

```
inRange(image,Scalar(170,100,0),Scalar(255,255,70),image);
```

and i detect object in blue, but I can't draw rectangle around the object.

Should I use mask? or something?

```
inRange(image,Scalar(170,100,0),Scalar(255,255,70),image);
GaussianBlur(image,image,Size(9,9),1.5);

for(int i = 2; i <image.cols-2;i++)
 for(int j = 2; j <image.rows-2;j++){
  if( image.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j-1)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i,j-1)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i,j+1)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j)[0] > 200 &&
    image.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[0] > 200 
)
{

    if(min_x > i)
        min_x = i;
    if(min_y >j)
        min_y = j;
    if(max_x < i)
        max_x =i;
    if(max_y < j)
        max_y = j;

}
 }
 if(!(max_x==0 && max_y==0 && min_x==image.rows && min_y == image.cols))
 {
    rectangle(image,Point(min_x,min_y),Point(max_x,max_y),CV_RGB(255,0,0),2);
 }

  imshow("working", image);
  if(waitKey(100) >= 0) break;
}
```

}

This isn't working and a run time error.
I don't know why.. help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

- Your image might be `CV_8U3C`, but inRange probably converts it to `CV_8U`, so better use for output a new Mat instance.
- Use `cv::findContours` to detect your area.
- Study `meanshift` used for tracking by opencv which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use RGB image for the inrange method. You should transform your image to HSV color space, and use hue range of blue then, which is 95-135. There are so many "blue" possibilities at RGB space.

```
inRange(image,Scalar(95,0,0),Scalar(135,255,255),image);
```

The result will be a binary image, just [find the contour](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#findcontours) and [draw bounding rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) around it.